# How to submit a value with a submit button AND by the enter button?

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

Can someone help me with some javascript code?

I would start a javascript function after click the submit button AND after pressing the 'Enter' key. I've made this code, seperately it works, but together the 'Enter' key doesn't works. What goes wrong?

Thanks!!

```
<form onsubmit="SubmitFormData(); return false;" id="myForm" method="post">

 Name:    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br />


<input type="submit" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("name");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   SubmitFormData();
  }
});
</script>

function SubmitFormData() {
var name = $("#name").val();
$.post("submit.php", { name: name },
function(data) {
 $('#results').html(data);
 $('#myForm')[0].reset();
});
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the user needs to do both? Click the submit button AND the enter key at the same time or in quick succession?

Comment: No, sorry for the inconvenience. It's or the submit button OR the enter key. But the function has to work by both.

Comment: If you want to submit the form inside the keyup callback, you don't need `document.getElementById("submitFormData").click();`. Just invoke `SubmitFormData()` directly.

Comment: Thanks, like this? It's not working yet...

Comment: It's still refreshing the page when I push enter.

Comment: @Terry, thanks it works now! The next step is to return the data when the enter button is pressed. 

I think when the enter button is pressed, the data reset directly? And by click submit the data saved by the php function?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SubmitFormData()` function will work only if you click on the `input` button (you added the `onclick` attribute to it).

You should remove it and add the following attribute to your `form`: `onsubmit="SubmitFormData(); return false;"`

**Obs.: change your `type` attribute on the input. The `type="button"` it's wrong. Use `type="submit"`.**

Comment: Thanks! Remove the whole submit button? When I delete only the onclick both doesn't work anymore.

Comment: No, you don't need to delete the whole button. Just remove the `onclick` attribute, because you won't need it anymore. Don't forget to change the `type` attribute to `submit`.

Comment: Hi William, thanks! It works now! Just one question, after pushing the enter button the input is not saved. I would like to echo the input, can you help me again?

Comment: Yes, you can send the whole form data to your json request using the `serialize` function, so you won't need to declare variables to each input of the form. Follow these steps:
1. Change `onsubmit="SubmitFormData(); return false;"` to `onsubmit="SubmitFormData(this); return false;"`
2. Change `function SubmitFormData() {` to `function SubmitFormData(form) {`
3. Change `var name = $("#name").val();` to `var form_data = $(form).serialize();`
4. Change `$.post("submit.php", { name: name },` to `$.post("submit.php", form_data,`

Hope it helps! =)